# Implementing onSlideClick for carousel component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using the ng-bootstrap bootstrap components.

I am still new to Angular2 and having trouble grasping some concepts.

The carousel component does not include an onClick event output.

I am trying to create my own while maintaining the information of the slide that I clicked.

Therefore I tried this:

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <template ngbSlide id="mySlide" (click)="onSlideClicked()">
    <img src="../assets/slide.jpg">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>MySlide</h3>
      <p>Just my slide.</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Which did not work and crashed. So I had two more ideas: Adding a clickevent to ngb-carousel itself (this does not give me information about the id) or adding a clickevent to the image with the same problem.

How would I implement a best practice onClick which would give me the id of the clicked object? Should I have double binded the id instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution myself:

Using the hashtag we can immidiately pass the carousel object into the function

```
<ngb-carousel  #currSlide (click)="onSlideClicked(currSlide)">
```

The method in the carousel.ts:

```
  onSlideClicked(value: any){
    console.log(value.activeId);
  }
```

returns the activeId aka active slide

Comment: I have the same problem, but I need to know which arrow is clicked, left or right, any ideas?